# Could not find org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6 when adding Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: java, android, firebase, crashlytics

I removed Fabrics Crashlytics to replace it with Firebase Crashlytics.

I followed the steps mentioned here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android

I get the error:

```
Could not find org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6/httpclient-4.5.6.pom
If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
Required by:
    project :myProject > com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1 > com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.1.1
```

Do you see how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Google's Maven Repository doesn't track `org.apache.httpcomponents`. This may work:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Firebaser here - I agree with this. Adding mavenCentral() (or better yet, jcenter()) to your buildscript repositories should solve this problem.